# How to disable mini-windows when switching apps in Kubuntu

Tags: plasma

I once disabled this feature and as far as I can recall, it was somewhere in kwin's or in Compositor's Setting, but I'm totally blank now and don't remember how I actually did it before.

What I'm talking about is this, below

[image]

I don't like this as I totally lose track of the window I'm currently working on, and if the count of instances is greater than 10 then its very difficult to pick the correct one.
I recently updated my system and since then I'm getting this, instead of getting a list of open windows.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This feature is configured by "Screen Edges" . Go to the System Settings->Workspace Behavior -> Screen Edges . Then click on the edge in the pseudo monitor where this action gets triggered , and select "No Action" . And if you triggered this action unintentionally , you can press Escape to get to the window where you've been. You wouldn't lose track of the windows. I sometimes use this feature even with more than 20 windows !

Comment: Open a terminal and run `kcmshell5 kwineffects`. Ignore any terminal output and maximize the window that appears. Scroll to "Window Management" and turn off "Present Windows". Click "Apply" in the lower right corner. Close the window.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Thanks everyone for your replies and special thanks to DK Bose, your solution solved my problem. Thanks again :-)

Answer (score 0):

This feature is configured by [Screen Edges](https://community.kde.org/KWin/Screen_Edges) . Go to `System Settings->Workspace Behavior ->Screen Edges` . Then click on the edge in the pseudo monitor where this action gets triggered , and select "No Action" .It should look like this :

[image]

And each time you triggered this action unintentionally , you can press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to get to the window where you've been. You wouldn't lose track of the windows. I sometimes use this feature even with more than 20 windows !